# Was Socrates a critic or a cynic?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, metaphilosophy

What is the difference between a 'critic' and a 'cynic' from pragmatic point of view? Can they be used interchangeably? In particular, was Socrates a critic or a cynic? What role each has in philosophical discourse?

Comment: This is more a question for [english.se] or [ell.se].

Comment: How to change the stack?

Comment: Only moderators can migrate to those sites, so I flagged your post for their attention.

Comment: Thanks Keelan. Is it too difficult for philosophers to answer this question..?

Comment: It's not suitable for this site. There may be some philosophers who know everything there is to know about wallpapers, but they wouldn't answer questions about that _here_.

Answer (score 2):

The use of **criticism** or **dialectics** can be traced back as far as to ancient Greek philosophers. **Socrates** as described in **Plato's dialogues**, was a critic and under some interpretations - also a cynic. Being a critic, he used to criticize his interlocutors' presumptions by finding (logical and other) weaknesses in their reasoning and positions. The role of his criticism meant not to demean but rather help find better answer to some question he or others posed. Through Socrates we learn that criticism is valuable and indispensable for understanding questions and answers; and it should be hence welcomed by those who want to improve upon their reasoning. The manner however by which Socrates communicated, could be - as I've said above - interpenetrated also as somewhat cynical due to his tendency to provoke his interlocutors by turning their positions seem absurd.

Every cynical remark carries some criticism. Cynicism may be thought of as pragmatic tool just as irony, humor and so on. Delivering criticism via being cynical might at times hurt the criticized subject, and hence might miss the point. Otherwise, sometimes it is exactly the cynicism (especially in social matters) that has ability to raise issues that are overlooked.

Note: From the above, it should follow that to criticize means to provide well-grounded reasoning rather than just saying that this or that is inadequate (as is done sometimes in everyday usage of the term). And, obviously, from the above, it also follows: the two terms "critic" and "cynic" should not be used interchangeably nor their roles in communication be mixed.